# Oracle backup and recovery using RMAN

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

Can some please provide a quick guide for backup and recovery of Oracle 11 DB?
I just need to test it very quickly so i don't need something too fancy, but should be scheduled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Performing Backup and Recovery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/backrest.htm#i1004902) in [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm) is what you are looking for.